# Jackson Get Key's Value From Root Array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to quickly parse out the root node of similar JSON like below:

```
[
  {"key":"foo", "value":123},
  {"key":"bar", "value":"Hello World!"},
  {"key":"far", "value":{"something":1}}
]
```

Simply put, I need to look at the "key"'s value (i.e. "foo", "bar", "far"), to determine if I need to fully deserialize the "value" portion to POJOs.

I have tried creating a class for POJO mapping, but that has a lot of overhead and it especially doesn't like a Map because the inside of my value is sometimes a value-type and sometimes more JSON.

Any ideas how I can traverse the keys quickly and then take the value out and deserialize it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to bind as a tree (ObjectMapper.readTree(), gives JsonNode of root node), traverse, and then deserialize values separately, using ObjectMapper.readValue(valueNode)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @StaxMan, can you please provide an example how I would do what you mentioned?

Comment: As to code sample, best way would be to join mailing list and ask other users for existing code, pointers. One further idea though: even if you use a POJO, you can define "value" to be of type java.lang.Object; which gives you a List, Map or wrapper type; and that too can be converted using "ObjectMapper.convertValue(objectValue, ActualBeanType.class);" based on what you see as "key" value.

Comment: Even more fascinating, I tried helping by adding a working example to @Stax's answer and it was rejected.  Funny.....